# Has anyone gotten Selenium Undetected ChromeDriver to work on a raspberry pi?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

Cant get Selenium Undetected ChromeDriver working on my raspberry pi. All googling I've done suggests there's no luck

I have tried installing the latest chromium version & installing older versions of undetected chromedriver

Comment: Please ask about the _specific technical problem_ you encounter when trying to get it working yourself. (Which specific Pi version you have also matters -- if you need aarch64 binaries versus 32-bit arm binaries that's not a trivial distinction). See [mre] guidelines; we should have enough details to produce the problem ourselves and be confident that we're hitting the exact same issue you had.

Comment: (The Raspberry Pi isn't all that unique a platform -- it's unlikely you've found a problem that can only be reproduced there and not on any other hardware -- so providing details of the problem will let even people who don't have a Pi work towards reproducing and fixing your issue; but none of that can happen without details: _Exactly_ which OS/distro you're on, _exactly_ which steps you followed, _exactly_ which error you encountered when trying to follow them).